# String to data type class

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want convert a string to datatype class, for this I use a [reference](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?479589-how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-class-name). Then I trying use a map than the follow code. But when I trying compile this I get

Error message:

> error: invalid conversion from 'std::map, void* (*)()>::mapped_type {aka void* (*)()}' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]

Code:

```
class C1 {
public:
  C1() { std::cout << "Object of class C1 created\n"; }
  static void * create() { return (void*)new C1; }
};

class C2 {
public:
C2() { std::cout << "Object of class C2 created\n"; }
static void * create() { return (void*)new C2; }
};

typedef void * (*fptr)();

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, fptr> fpmap;
  fpmap.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("C1"), C1::create));
  fpmap.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("C2"), C2::create));

  std::string classname;
  std::cout << "Insert classname :" << std::flush;
  std::cin >> classname;

  void * obj = fpmap["C1"];
}
```

Comment: I hope you have a plan how to release allocated memory and destruct created objects properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
void * obj = fpmap["C1"]();
```

A function pointer isn't directly convertible to a `void*`. I you want `obj` to point to the function itself, declare it as `fptr`. If you want to call the function and have `obj` point to what it returns, you need to call the function (extra `()`).

Comment: Or, presumably, `void * obj = fpmap[classname]();`